# Experimental DevMode arguments in IntelliJ IDEA launch configuration

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I cannot use all the devmode parameters in IntelliJ IDEA launch configuration. Because if I add, for instance, `-XdisableCastChecking` or `-XdisableClassMetadata` I get the following output in console:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55232', transport: 'socket'
Unknown argument: -XdisableCastChecking
Google Web Toolkit 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT
DevMode [-[no]startServer] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel (ERROR|WARN|INFO|TRACE|DEBUG|SPAM|ALL)] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-[no]superDevMode] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-modulePathPrefix ] [-workDir dir] [-XmethodNameDisplayMode (NONE|ONLY_METHOD_NAME|ABBREVIATED|FULL)] [-sourceLevel [auto, 1.7, 1.8]] [-XjsInteropMode (NONE|JS)] [-[no]incremental] [-setProperty name=value,value...] module[s] 

where 
  -[no]startServer         Starts a servlet container serving the directory specified by the -war flag. (defaults to ON)
  -port                    Specifies the TCP port for the embedded web server (defaults to 8888)
  -logdir                  Logs to a file in the given directory, as well as graphically
  -logLevel                The level of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, SPAM or ALL (defaults to INFO)
  -gen                     Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be saved in the specified directory
  -bindAddress             Specifies the bind address for the code server and web server (defaults to 127.0.0.1)
  -codeServerPort          Specifies the TCP port for the code server (defaults to 9997 for classic Dev Mode or 9876 for Super Dev Mode)
  -[no]superDevMode        Runs Super Dev Mode instead of classic Development Mode. (defaults to ON)
  -server                  Specify a different embedded web server to run (must implement ServletContainerLauncher)
  -startupUrl              Automatically launches the specified URL
  -war                     The directory into which deployable output files will be written (defaults to 'war')
  -deploy                  The directory into which deployable but not servable output files will be written (defaults to 'WEB-INF/deploy' under the -war directory/jar, and may be the same as the -extra directory/jar)
  -extra                   The directory into which extra files, not intended for deployment, will be written
  -modulePathPrefix        The subdirectory inside the war dir where DevMode will create module directories. (defaults empty for top level)
  -workDir                 The compiler's working directory for internal use (must be writeable; defaults to a system temp dir)
  -XmethodNameDisplayMode  EXPERIMENTAL: Specifies method display name mode for chrome devtools: NONE, ONLY_METHOD_NAME, ABBREVIATED or FULL (defaults to NONE)
  -sourceLevel             Specifies Java source level (defaults to 1.7)
  -XjsInteropMode          EXPERIMENTAL: Specifies JsInterop mode: NONE or JS (defaults to NONE)
  -[no]incremental         Compiles faster by reusing data from the previous compile. (defaults to ON)
  -setProperty             Set the values of a property in the form of propertyName=value1[,value2...].
and 
  module[s]                Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to host
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55232', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

[Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/6ox0do)

Whereas I can use them in my maven GWT plugin without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the CodeHaus Mojo gwt-maven-plugin, it will only pass arguments that are supported by the forked tool; launch with `mvn -X` to get the exact list of arguments passed to DevMode.

See https://github.com/gwt-maven-plugin/gwt-maven-plugin/blob/ef093f7f844668511ab74829749dc0b11d1e13ac/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt/shell/RunMojo.java, you won't find any mention of `disable` in there. Similarly, http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html doesn't list them.
You can have them in your configuration but Maven will only inject corresponding fields depending on whether the Mojo (goal) have them (put differently, you could put a `<foo>bar</foo>` in your plugin configuration and you wouldn't have any error.